# How to get an element from the ForeignKey of a class?

Tags: django

My models:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    test_details = models.TextField()
    child_test = models.ForeignKey("ChildTest")

class ChildTest(models.Model):
    child_test_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    child_test_age = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

My admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from testing.models import Test, ChildTest


class AdminTest(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'test_name': ('test_name',),
                           'test_details': ('test_details',),
                           'child_test':('child_test',),
                           }
    list_display = ('test_name', 'test_details', 'child_test')

class AdminLittleTest(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = { 'child_test_name': ('child_test_name',),
                           'child_test_age': ('child_test_age',),
                           }

admin.site.register(Test, AdminTest)
admin.site.register(ChildTest, AdminLittleTest)
```

Where it says `'child_test':('child_test',),` I actually want to see the `ChildTest`'s `child_test_name`. I have tried different things like `child_test.child_test_name`, but I always end up with an error that the field is missing from the `Test` class.

Comment: You dont need to use "" when referencing another model as foreignkey. Also for the ChildTest Class to be represented with its name use: 

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.child_test_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use ForeignKeys in [`prepopulated_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields):

```
prepopulated_fields doesn’t accept DateTimeField, ForeignKey, nor ManyToManyField fields.
```

So what you are asking is not possible with `prepopulated_fields`.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first error I got, so I was trying to find some kind of a work around for that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `child_test__child_test_name`